# Making an HTML table list monthly snapshots of a variable

Tags: php, mysql

The table below lists `username` by `total` descending.  How can I make each row list whoever had the highest `total` on the `$date` listed in the first column?

```
$query = "SELECT username, datesubmitted, COUNT(1) AS total 
    FROM submission 
    GROUP BY username

ORDER BY total DESC"

$result = mysql_query($query);

$date = strtotime("January 1, 2010");

$arr = array();

echo "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $date = strtotime("+1 month", $date);

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td >'.date("F j, Y", $date).'</td>';
            echo '<td >'.stripslashes($row["username"]).'</a></td>';
            echo '<td >'.number_format(($row["total"])).'</td>';
            echo '</tr>'; 
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the grouping in mysql as well, no need count in PHP:

```
SELECT count(*), username, datesubmitted
    FROM submission 
    GROUP BY username, month(datesubmitted)
```

Now you can just iterate over the result in display the table

Comment: What do I put in the HTML table column to get the username with the highest count(*) for each $date?